# In Dataframe, remove parentheses and dash from phone number and also take care about international prefix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In data frame, how to remove unnecessary thing from Contact number

**df**

```
Id Phone
1  (+1)123-456-7890
2  (123)-(456)-(7890)
3  123-456-7890
```

**Final Output**

```
Id  Phone
1   1234567890
2   1234567890
3   1234567890
```

Comment: How do you decide that `(123)` and `(456)` and `(7890)` are necessary but `(+1)` isn't? And what if you run in to an actual international number where the leading (+ _country_code_) is not extraneous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a regex with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) here:

```
df['Phone2'] = df['Phone'].str.replace(r'^(?:\(\+\d+\))|\D', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
   Id               Phone      Phone2
0   1    (+1)123-456-7890  1234567890
1   2  (123)-(456)-(7890)  1234567890
2   3        123-456-7890  1234567890
```

regex:

```
^(?:\(\+\d+\)) # match a (+0) leading identifier
|              # OR
\D             # match a non-digit
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W11x4Z/1)

###### notes on the international prefix:

This might be important to keep.

Keep the prefixes:

```
df['Phone2'] = df['Phone'].str.replace(r'[^+\d]', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
   Id               Phone          Phone2
0   1    (+1)123-456-7890    +11234567890
1   2  (123)-(456)-(7890)      1234567890
2   3        123-456-7890      1234567890
3   4  (+380)123-456-7890  +3801234567890
```

Only drop a specific prefix (here `+1`):

```
df['Phone2'] = df['Phone'].str.replace(r'^(?:\(\+1\))|[^+\d]', '', regex=True)
# or, more flexible
df['Phone2'] = df['Phone'].str.replace(r'(?:\+1\D)|[^+\d]', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
   Id               Phone          Phone2
0   1    (+1)123-456-7890      1234567890
1   2  (123)-(456)-(7890)      1234567890
2   3        123-456-7890      1234567890
3   4  (+380)123-456-7890  +3801234567890
```

Comment: I might restrict the the `(+1)` match to only matching a solitary 1 after the plus rather than any sequence of digits; otherwise you're throwing away part of a non-US phone number. Maybe restrict the non-digit alternate to leave the `+` alone, too (when not part of the `(+1)` case), since it's part of the standard international format.

Comment: @MarkReed I'll add some notes on the international prefix. I admit I answered the literal question ;)